# How to remove a relation in surrealdb

Tags: surrealdb

```sql
RELATE (
  SELECT * from user where username = 'user_male'
)->interested_in->gender:female;
```

I used the above `RELATE` statement to specify that the `user_male` user is interested in women.

I can't figure out how to UNRELATE this user to that gender; or for example to SELECT all users that are interested in women

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edge `interested_in` becomes **its own table** from which you can delete rows with the `DELETE` statement.

To *"unrelate"* the relation, we only need to delete every entry from `interested_in` where `in.username` is `'user_male` and where `out` is `gender:female`.

```sql
DELETE interested_in WHERE in.username = 'user_male' AND out = 'gender:female';
```

Comment: thank you.. i went the very long route of: DELETE interested_in WHERE gender:female INSIDE ->gender AND count(array::distinct(array::concat(<-user, (SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = "user_male")))) = 1 RETURN BEFORE